# Raspberry Pi 4 + Docker run multiple cpus

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I have an application that runs docker to execute a spring boot app while also running ffmpeg commands for audio transcoding. Using the raspberry pi 4 (4gb ram) the container is only using 1 CPU which is causing the app to be slow. Attempting to set multiple CPUs for the container causes an error. What kernel is available which allows for multi cpu support with docker + raspberry pi 4?

My docker file is as follows;

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim-stretch
VOLUME /tmp

ADD ./target/app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
EXPOSE 5001 5002

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

I am attempting to run the container with the following command;

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 --memory=200mb --cpuset-cpus="0-3" my_app
```

But I have the following warnings which prevent running multi cpu images;

```
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

What OS/Kernel would allow me to run multi cpu support on the Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: Was there any progress, i'm curious too on this as I started going into ARMs compiler.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't revisted this issue in the last year.